# module "QtQml.Models" is not installed

Tags: qt-creator, qt5

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I removed the official qtcreator in order to install the modified version from the software center because I'd like to try the SDK. Fortunately, the docs are now included in the official installation. 
Unfortunately, there is still something missing: the official examples. Luckily I had my old and official installation still on my harddrive and then, after some tries, I copied the examples to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples and change the permission. Then QtCreator detected examples and I was able to select them from the examples section. But there are still one problem remaining.

After running some QML examples (like StocQt) I get a small blank window and the message

```
module "QtQml.Models" is not installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `qtdeclarative5-models-plugin` package, the [Qt 5 Models QML plugin.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qtdeclarative5-models-plugin)

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-models-plugin
```